# Return array of hashes in perl

Tags: perl, perl-module

The below function  logins into a router, executes a command to get the IPsec session status and returns the interface name and ip address as string. Instead of returning a string, I want the function to return array of hashes. Can someone help me out with that ?

```
sub cryptoSessionStatus {
    my ($self,$interface)  = @_;
    my $status  = 0;
    my $peer_ip = 0;

    #command to check the tunnel status
    my $cmd     = 'command goes here ' . $interface;
    #$self->_login();
    my $tunnel_status = $self->_login->exec($cmd);

    #Regex to match the 'tunnel status' and 'peer ip' string in the cmd output
    #Session status: DOWN/UP
    #Peer: x.x.x.x
    foreach my $line (  $tunnel_status ) {
      if ( $line =~ m/Session\s+status:\s+(.*)/ ) {
            $status = $1;
      }
      if ( $line =~ m/Peer:\s+(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)/ ) {
            $peer_ip = $1;
      }
    }

    return ($status,$peer_ip);
}
```

Function call:

```
 my $tunnel_obj =  test::Cryptotunnels->new('host'=> 'ip');

my $crypto_sessions = $tunnel_obj->cryptoSessionStatus("tunnel1");
```

Comment: Do you mean you want there to be a hash of Status => Ip?  And  you would like that returned?

Comment: @Ed Dunn  I want the ip and status to be returned as array of hashes               Array = (
    {
      ip => "x.x.x.x",
       status     => "up",
      } 
  );

Comment: what does the output look like?  Can we get a sample?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
my @session_states;
my $status;
foreach my $line (  $tunnel_status ) {
    if ( $line =~ m/Session\s+status:\s+(.*)/ ) {
        $status = $1;
    }
    if ( $line =~ m/Peer:\s+(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)/ ) {
        push @session_states, { ip => $1 , status => $status };
        $status = ""
    }
}
return \@session_states;
#
# called like so
#
my $tunnel_obj =  test::Cryptotunnels->new('host'=> 'ip');
my $crypto_sessions = $tunnel_obj->cryptoSessionStatus("tunnel1");
for my $obj (@$crypto_sessions) {
    print $obj->{ip}, "\n";
    print $obj->{status}, "\n";
}
```

This assumes the `Session status` line appears *before* the `Peer` line in the output.  If its the other way around (you didn't supply a sample of what the router output looks like, so I have to guess a bit...) ie: if the `Peer` line is before the `Session status` line then it should be like this:

```
my @session_states;
my $peer_ip;
foreach my $line (  $tunnel_status ) {
    if ( $line =~ m/Session\s+status:\s+(.*)/ ) {
        push @session_states, { ip => $peer_ip , status => $1 };
        $peer_ip = "";
    }
    if ( $line =~ m/Peer:\s+(\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)/ ) {
        $peer_ip = $1;
    }
}
return \@session_states;
#
# called the same as above
#
```

There's no real difference in the algorithm - whichever comes second in the output - `Peer` or `Session status` - defines the end of the entry and a hash is created with the two entries and pushed onto the `@session_states` array.

Comment: In an earlier version of this answer, I didn't pick-up the dependence on the order of appearance of the lines in the output.  That version of the code probably would not have worked.